# Getting empty screen when running servlet application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I've just started working on servlets and i'm a newbie. I have developed a html page with a submit button which invokes the servlet.Here is the html code for it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A simple revision of servlets</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="Idiot">
    <input type="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The deployment descriptor is as follows named as web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>TangoCharlie</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.web.Revise</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TangoCharlie</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Idiot</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The code for servlet is as follows which is named as :Revise.java

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Revise extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    //out.println("<html><body><h3>Hello</h3></body></html>");
    out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

I have maintained the following directories inside webapps of tomcat server.
    webapps->Revision->page.html

```
webapps->Revision->WEB-INF->web.xml

webapps->Revision->WEB-INF->classes->com->example->web->Revise.class
```

When i run page.html in Mozilla Firefox and click on submit,i get a blank page.
When i run page.html in Chrome ,i get the following message:

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8080/Revision/Idiot.It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Where am i wrong ???

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace? If so, please post it.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Revisio/Idiot  spell check for "Revision" ?

Comment: @Metalhead : I have checked the spellings correctly .This is not the issue
Secondly,i am getting the html page on screen and i'm not accessing servlet directly.See it is mapped thru Deployment Descriptor.The problem occurs after clicking the Submit Button

Comment: Try changing the `url-pattern` to this: <url-pattern>/Idiot/</url-pattern>

Comment: Have u tried redeploying it again? Doesn't seem to be any code issue here.

Comment: Check your server logs and post the stacktrace if there is any.

Comment: @Metalhead :As u suggested,restarting tomcat solved the problem.
Thanx
I have read that we must restart tomcat everytime we make changes in our files.But sometimes it works without restart and needs just a refresh.
So what should i follow -restart every time or is there a solution like using eclipse or something...!
As restarting tomcat again abd again is very annoying.

Comment: Any changes made to the xml descriptor always need a restart. The changes made to html don't need a restart coz it's not something that gets compiled. For JSP also you can get away with restart if you delete it's generated .class file from temp/work forlder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Metalhead i just needed to restart tomcat.

The typo "Revisio" is my mistake during copying and pasting as the page on chrome spreaded out towrds right side and i missed that character 'n' in 'Revision'.I strongly apologise for that.

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:8080/Revisio/Idiot`

See the **typo** its `Revision` and **Not** `Revisio`